# IDXGIFactory4::CreateSwapChain returns DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL

Tags: directx-12

I am creating my Swapchain like this

```
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> factory;
CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory4), (void**)&factory);

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
scd.BufferCount = 2;
scd.BufferDesc.Width = mWidth;
scd.BufferDesc.Height = mHeight;
scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
scd.OutputWindow = mHwnd;
scd.Windowed = true;
scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> swapchain;
factory->CreateSwapChain(mQueue.Get(), &scd, &swapchain);
```

In Debug mode, this works fine, but in Release (either in x86 or x64), CreateSwapChain returns `DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is working in Debug mode, but not in Release mode?

Thanks!

Note: I'm using Direct3D 12

Comment: You should replace uuid-ptr pair arguments with the [`IID_PPV_ARGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727(v=vs.85).aspx) macro.  That way you avoid accidentally mismatching the declared type. So it would be `CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));`

Comment: For any late comers, CreateSwapChain also doesn't work if you try to be too smart with your format declaration when within a class, declaring format as a static const in the class header will have you scratching your head for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Yay :)

I forgot to link the DX12 libs....